# Lags caused by bad Game Loop

Tags: java, performance

I need help fixing my gameloop. Sometimes the game feels very laggy and I think the reason is that the tick() method is called slower then the render() method. What I want is that update is called as often as possible and the tick method gets executed with some kind of value that determines how fast thinks are going. For example the value is 0.8 and I just multiply it to determine how fast Things should go.

And I think my current gameloop is just a mess!

```
public void run() {

    init();

    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / targetTicksPerSecond;
    double timePerFrame = 1000000000 / targetFramesPerSecond;
    double delta = 0;
    double delta2 = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    long renderTimer = 0;
    int ticks = 0;


    while (running) {

        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        delta2 += (now - lastTime) / timePerFrame;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1) {

            tick();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }
        if(delta2 >= 1) {              
            render();
            renderTimer++;
            delta2--;
        }
        if (timer >= 1000000000) {
            currentTicks = ticks;
            currentFPS = (int) renderTimer;

            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
            renderTimer = 0;
        }





    }


    stop();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.